# Set TrustedHosts on Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to deploy a build to a VM using the Manage IIS App agent task on Visual Studio Team Services. However, when I attempt to connect via HTTP, it comes back with the following error:

*The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts*

Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to deploy over HTTPs for reasons beyond my control so I'm trying to get around this issue by setting the VM as a trusted host, but I can't figure out how to do this using VS Online.

Comment: have you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t add trusted host to Hosted build agent (Get access is denied result if add trusted host via winrm command during build)

You can setup a new build agent and configure it to add trusted host with winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputer"} command, after that, using this build agent to build/release.

About how to setup a new build agent, you can refer to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows) article.